# Rotate on hover doesnt work?

Tags: html, css

I want a small rotate when I hover my div. It does work on a other div but it is not working on this one?

Here is my code:

```css
.more,
.more:visited {
  color: #fff;
  min-width: 88px;
  height: 80px;
  display: block;
  background-color: green;
  padding: 22px 28px 0 28px;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -40px;
  right: 34px;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease;
  transition: all 0.7s ease;
}
.more:hover {
  color: #fff;
  transform: translateX(-230px);
}
```

```html
<div id="meer"><a id="kleur" class="more" style="width: 105px; height:105px; padding: 32px 28px 22px 30px; mix-blend-mode: multiply;" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">LEES MEER</a>
</div>
```

Comment: You're not adding a rotation though. You're adding a translate.

Comment: Why the jQuery and JavaScript tags?

Answer (score 3):

Changing `translateX()` for `rotate()` makes your div rotate correctly.

```css
.more, .more:visited {
    color:#fff;
    min-width:88px;
    height:80px;
    display:block;
    background-color: green;
    padding:22px 28px 0 28px;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box;
    position:absolute;
    bottom:-40px;
    right:34px;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.7s ease; 
    transition: all 0.7s ease;
}
.more:hover {
    color:#fff;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}
```

```html
<div id="meer">
    <a id="kleur" class="more" href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" title="<?php the_title(); ?>">LEES MEER</a>
</div>
```